# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

the screenshot

[image]

full screenshot

[image]

I have joined two RDD's using pyspark but while splitting them and fetching the details of the table I am getting below errors

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

the code that I am working on:

```
orderitems = sc.textFile("/user/zzz/data/retail_db/order_items/part-00000")
orderitemsmap = orderitems.map(lambda oi: (int(oi.split(",")[1]),float(oi.split(",")[4])))
ordersReduce = orderitemsmap.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)

orders = sc.textFile("/user/zzz/data/retail_db/orders/part-00000")
ordersmap = orders.map(lambda oi:(int(oi.split(",")[0]),oi.split(",")[3]))

orderstatus = ordersReduce.join(ordersmap)

renvStatus = orderstatus.map(lambda oi: oi.split(",")[1]) 
for i in renvStatus.take(10):print i
```

Comment: can you show us the error too

Comment: this current screenshot does not cover entire error, can you copy and paste the entire error

Comment: Do not add pictures of the text. Copy & paste the text into your question.

Comment: the error is in `renvStatus = orderstatus.map(lambda oi: oi.split(",")[1])` as `orderstatus` is a RDD[Tuple2] and you can't split tuple2. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

based on your code, you are trying to apply split method on a tuple. split method is available on strings. so, it could be that `oi` is a tuple and you may want to access an element of the tuple and then apply split on the element. again, it will work only if its a string.

Answer (score 0):

Only string object have the method split.
If your tuple object (oi?) is a tuple of string may be you want to:

```
"".join(oi)  # ('a', 'b', 'c') => 'abc'
```